# Crash when creating object in Typhoon

Tags: objective-c, typhoon

I'm experiencing a crash in TyphoonComponentFactory.m when trying to instantiate an object - this line crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

```
279:[pool setObject:instance forKey:definition.key];
```

Or sometimes this one:

```
276:id instance = [pool objectForKey:definition.key];
```

All the variables - pool, instance, definition, look right at the time it crashes, in the debugger. Earlier in the program's execution (but not much earlier, i.e. the same runloop) I've set up my TyphoonComponentFactory and made it the default factory. Is there anything that could be causing this? I had a vague theory that the factory is created too late for the callers but... pretty weak.

Typhoon version 1.8.2. Here's the assembly:

```
#import "EndpointQueueAssembly.h"
#import "EndpointQueue.h"
#import "URLStorage.h"
#import "EndpointHTTPMethods.h"
#import "EndpointURLStrings.h"
#import "HTTPRequestOperationFactory.h"
#import "Services.h"
#import "ChatImageCheck.h"

@implementation EndpointQueueAssembly

-(id)endpointQueue
{

    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass: [EndpointQueue class] properties:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {

        [definition setScope:TyphoonScopeSingleton];

    }];

}

-(id)urlStorage
{

    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass: [URLStorage class]];

}

-(id)endpointHTTPMethods
{

    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass: [EndpointHTTPMethods class]];

}

-(id)chatImageCheck
{

    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass: [ChatImageCheck class]];

}

-(id)endpointURLStrings
{

    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass: [EndpointURLStrings class] properties:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {

        [definition injectProperty:@selector(urlStorage)];

    }];

}

-(id)httpRequestOperationFactory
{

    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass: [HTTPRequestOperationFactory class] properties:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition) {

        [definition injectProperty:@selector(endpointHTTPMethods)];

        [definition injectProperty:@selector(endpointURLStrings)];

    }];

}

-(id)services
{

    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[Services class] properties:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {

        [definition setScope:TyphoonScopeSingleton];

    }];

}

@end
```

Stack trace, for a crash on line 276:

```
Thread 65, Queue : NSOperationQueue 0x12434e90
#0  0x0473756b in -[__NSDictionaryM objectForKey:] ()
#1  0x0033c2dd in -[TyphoonComponentFactory sharedInstanceForDefinition:fromPool:] at /Users/nicklocking/Documents/primus-ios/NBFIOSCore/Pods/Typhoon/Source/Factory/TyphoonComponentFactory.m:276
#2  0x0033cb34 in -[TyphoonComponentFactory(TyphoonDefinitionRegisterer) objectForDefinition:] at /Users/nicklocking/Documents/primus-ios/NBFIOSCore/Pods/Typhoon/Source/Factory/TyphoonComponentFactory.m:315
#3  0x0033b01d in -[TyphoonComponentFactory componentForKey:] at /Users/nicklocking/Documents/primus-ios/NBFIOSCore/Pods/Typhoon/Source/Factory/TyphoonComponentFactory.m:151
#4  0x046a291d in __invoking___ ()
#5  0x046a282a in -[NSInvocation invoke] ()
#6  0x00335f69 in -[TyphoonBlockComponentFactory forwardInvocation:] at /Users/nicklocking/Documents/primus-ios/NBFIOSCore/Pods/Typhoon/Source/Factory/Block/TyphoonBlockComponentFactory.m:97
#7  0x0469e2da in ___forwarding___ ()
#8  0x0469e0ee in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#9  0x00022647 in +[CascadeItemRenderOperation isCurrentProfileWithDictionary:] at /Users/nicklocking/Documents/primus-ios/NBFIOSCore/Shared/CascadeItemRenderOperation.m:166
#10 0x00022d3b in +[CascadeItemRenderOperation countOfUnreadChatsWithDictionary:] at /Users/nicklocking/Documents/primus-ios/NBFIOSCore/Shared/CascadeItemRenderOperation.m:205
#11 0x00021c7c in +[CascadeItemRenderOperation renderWithDictionary:] at /Users/nicklocking/Documents/primus-ios/NBFIOSCore/Shared/CascadeItemRenderOperation.m:79
#12 0x001002b2 in -[GrindrGridViewPreRenderOperation main] at /Users/nicklocking/Documents/primus-ios/NBFIOSCore/Grindr/GrindrGridViewPreRenderOperation.m:38
#13 0x02d0dc79 in -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] ()
#14 0x02c8a9c8 in -[NSOperation start] ()
#15 0x02d0ff44 in __NSOQSchedule_f ()
#16 0x04d164d0 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#17 0x04d02fe0 in _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke ()
#18 0x04d164d0 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#19 0x04d04eb7 in _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
#20 0x04d05127 in _dispatch_worker_thread2 ()
#21 0x05045dab in _pthread_wqthread ()
```

Values of relevant objects:

self: TyphoonBlockComponentFactory with all relevant objects available in the registry.
definition: "Definition: class='AuthenticationDetails', key='authenticationDetails'"
pool: NSDictionary, 0 key/value pairs
instance: id, uninitialised pointer.

Here's the stack for the main thread at the time - also contains Typhoon references:

```
Thread 1, Queue : com.apple.main-thread
#0  0x05081802 in __psynch_mutexwait ()
#1  0x05047945 in _pthread_mutex_lock ()
#2  0x050477ac in pthread_mutex_lock ()
#3  0x0443a498 in objc_sync_enter ()
#4  0x0033c288 in -[TyphoonComponentFactory sharedInstanceForDefinition:fromPool:] at /Users/nicklocking/Documents/primus-ios/NBFIOSCore/Pods/Typhoon/Source/Factory/TyphoonComponentFactory.m:275
#5  0x0033cb34 in -[TyphoonComponentFactory(TyphoonDefinitionRegisterer) objectForDefinition:] at /Users/nicklocking/Documents/primus-ios/NBFIOSCore/Pods/Typhoon/Source/Factory/TyphoonComponentFactory.m:315
#6  0x0033b01d in -[TyphoonComponentFactory componentForKey:] at /Users/nicklocking/Documents/primus-ios/NBFIOSCore/Pods/Typhoon/Source/Factory/TyphoonComponentFactory.m:151
#7  0x046a291d in __invoking___ ()
#8  0x046a282a in -[NSInvocation invoke] ()
#9  0x00335f69 in -[TyphoonBlockComponentFactory forwardInvocation:] at /Users/nicklocking/Documents/primus-ios/NBFIOSCore/Pods/Typhoon/Source/Factory/Block/TyphoonBlockComponentFactory.m:97
#10 0x0469e2da in ___forwarding___ ()
#11 0x0469e0ee in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#12 0x000735e7 in -[Profile(Custom) isMe] at /Users/nicklocking/Documents/primus-ios/NBFIOSCore/Utils/Profile+Custom.m:74
#13 0x0022a0eb in -[Profile(GrindrGridViewHash) grindrGridViewHash] at /Users/nicklocking/Documents/primus-ios/NBFIOSCore/Shared/Profile+GrindrGridViewHash.m:84
#14 0x000ff3ed in -[GrindrGridViewPreRenderCache preRenderManagedObjectsForBackgroundExecution:] at /Users/nicklocking/Documents/primus-ios/NBFIOSCore/Grindr/GrindrGridViewPreRenderCache.m:105
#15 0x000ff174 in -[GrindrGridViewPreRenderCache preRenderManagedObjects:] at /Users/nicklocking/Documents/primus-ios/NBFIOSCore/Grindr/GrindrGridViewPreRenderCache.m:87
#16 0x00041c8f in -[GrindrGridView endUpdates] at /Users/nicklocking/Documents/primus-ios/NBFIOSCore/Shared/GrindrGridView.m:825
#17 0x002343d2 in -[CascadeDataSource controllerDidChangeContent:] at /Users/nicklocking/Documents/primus-ios/NBFIOSCore/Grindr/CascadeDataSource.m:137
#18 0x0276e347 in -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:] ()
#19 0x02d0c049 in __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke ()
#20 0x04709f04 in __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ ()
#21 0x04661efb in _CFXNotificationPost ()
#22 0x02c45e41 in -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] ()
#23 0x02670a13 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] ()
#24 0x0270ffaf in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:withDeletions:withUpdates:withRefreshes:] ()
#25 0x0266beb8 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] ()
#26 0x0266b649 in -[NSManagedObjectContext processPendingChanges] ()
#27 0x0269a4cc in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _parentProcessSaveRequest:inContext:error:] ()
#28 0x02712a14 in __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke ()
#29 0x02694b81 in internalBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform ()
#30 0x04d164d0 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#31 0x04d05439 in _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke ()
#32 0x04d164d0 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#33 0x04d04726 in _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF ()
#34 0x0471343e in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ ()
#35 0x046545cb in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#36 0x046539d3 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#37 0x046537eb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#38 0x053ee5ee in GSEventRunModal ()
#39 0x053ee42b in GSEventRun ()
#40 0x03513f9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#41 0x0000e704 in main at /Users/nicklocking/Documents/primus-ios/NBFIOSCore/Shared/main.m:18
```

Further update:

It seems like Typhoon is defaulting to TyphoonScopeObjectGraph, which is apparently not thread-safe. We switched all non-singletons to TyphoonScopePrototype, and we now experience crashes in TyphoonCallStack -pop, in line 59, `[_storage removeLastObject]`. Seems to be an exception of some sort but the debugger doesn't spit anything useful out.

Comment: What version of Typhoon are you using? What does your assembly look like?

Comment: Added assembly and version.

Comment: Some questions: can you post the stack trace when crash happens? (specially the Typhoon framework part, and from the crash line to the crash place). Which values do `pool`, `instance` and `definition` have? Which of the objects is Typhoon trying to build? Are you seeing several threads accessing Typhoon? (Typhoon should be mostly thread-safe, but accident happens).

Comment: Stack trace and all other information added. I'm seeing the main thread also accessing Typhoon stuff in this instance, but this is not always the case.

Comment: We've tracked down a clue to the problem - everything seems to be coming up as TyphoonScopeObjectGraph by default. As this isn't thread-safe, and we do a lot of stuff in the background, we're seeing a lot of crashes. Is this a known issue or a configuration problem on our end?

Comment: Further update - changed everything to ScopePrototype, now experience crashes.

Comment: It’s strange, because some of those methods has synchronized access. You are actually blocked in the main thread trying to get into one of those synchronized blocks (nothing bad in that). I have look around and there is only one usage of `objectGraphSharedInstances` which is not synchronized (L324). You might want to try to put a @synchronize around that `if` block. The problem might be worse, because I think the idea of the object graph objects is not prepared for multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot comment on your post (haven't enough reputation):

Yes, if you create components from different threads - it can be reason of crashes. Typhoon is not threaded-safe now(we are using NSMutableArray, NSMutableDictionary which are not threaded-safe, during object creation).

You can fix it by wrapping Typhoon call into serial queue or synchronized statement.. Or we can do it inside Typhoon (but it will be Typhoon 2.0 feature - hard to maintain two versions at same time)

**Update:**

Typhoon 2.0 is now thread-safe.

Comment: Argh. Ok, we're going to try wrapping TyphoonComponentFactory -objectForDefinition: in a @synchronized block. Putting all the calls into a serial queue is not a good solution for us because we use a lot of NSOperationQueue objects that create these objects.

Answer (score 1):

Here's our solution, which seems to work pretty well:

```
#import "TyphoonComponentFactory+SwizzledObjectForDefinition.h"
#import "JRSwizzle.h"

@implementation TyphoonComponentFactory (SwizzledObjectForDefinition)

+ (void)swizzleMethods
{
    SEL objectForDefinitionSelector = sel_registerName("objectForDefinition:");
    [TyphoonComponentFactory jr_swizzleMethod: objectForDefinitionSelector
                                   withMethod: @selector(swizzledObjectForDefinition:)
                                        error: nil];
}

// Synchronize objectForDefinition
- (id)swizzledObjectForDefinition:(TyphoonDefinition *)definition
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        return [self swizzledObjectForDefinition:definition];
    }
}

@end
```

We also declare all scopes as either Singleton or Prototype.

Comment: From your testing, just having all the scopes as Singleton or Prototype wasn’t enough?

Comment: No, it crashed like crazy.